# Python if mysql row not equal to imput

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python, python-3.8

i use the **mysql.connector** module for my script.

here my script with my try to check:
my database structure:
name, type, prem, block

```
class database():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Database = mysql.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            password='',
            auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
        )
        self.cursor = self.Database.cursor()

    def GetProfileInformations(self, name):
        args = name.split(' ')
        found =  self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM list.raids WHERE name=' + args[0])
        sql =  self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM list.raids')
        rc = self.cursor.fetchall(sql)
        f = self.cursor.fetchall(found)
        # Check is imput equal to name 
        for _ in f:
            if not found:
                return
        for row in rc:
            try:
                if row[0] == args[0]:
                    if row[3] == 1:
                        if row[2] == 1:
                            print(f"Name {row[0]} found with 1")
                        else:
                            print(f"Name: {row[0]} found with 0")
                    else:
                        print(f"Name: {row[0]} found but is blocked")
            except:
                print("any error")
        self.cursor.close()
```

Now is my question why dont work the if exist function not ?

```
            if not found:
                return
```

have a nice day and thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this cursor attributes to check if your query has results or not:

```
if not found.with_rows:
   print("No records found")
```

You can also use:

```
if found.rowcount <= 0:
    print("No records found")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved for me self:

```
import mysql.connector as mysql

class database():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Database = mysql.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            password='',
            auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
        )
        self.cursor = self.Database.cursor(buffered=True)

    def IsInSQL(self, name):
        self.cursor.execute(f'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT name AS name FROM list.raids WHERE name = "{name}")')
        f = self.cursor.fetchall()
        if not f:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def GetProfileInformations(self, name):
        args = name.split(' ')
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM list.raids')
        rc = self.cursor.fetchall()
        if not self.IsInSQL(args[0]):
            print("nicht gefunden")
        for row in rc:
            try:
                if row[0] == args[0]:
                    if row[3] == 1:
                        if row[2] == 1:
                            print("")
                        else:
                            print("")
                    else:
                        print("not found")

            except:
                print("lel")
        self.cursor.close()
```